# "Out of range" error converting datetime2 to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table (`table1`) with `StartDate, StartTime, EndTime`, all `datetime2` and an `OverMidnight` boolean which specifies if the `EndDate` will be different (+1) from the `StartDate`.

I need to move these to another table (`table2`) with the columns `StartDate` and an `EndDate`, both need to be the `datetime` type, and use `StartDate` with `StartTime` to get the new `StartDate` and `StartDate`, `OverMidnight`, and `EndTime` to get the `EndDate`.

No matter what I have tried it gives me an error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187819.aspx) and [DATETIME2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) have different acceptable date ranges.

DATETIME:

> January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

DATETIME2:

> 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31

I would check whether you have any dates in your original data out of the `DATETIME` range or whether your conversion code is creating dates outside the `DATETIME` range in error.

Comment: Ah yes, it was a malformed date, I didn't want to go through 8000 records and manually change broken ones, so I changed my query to the first 10 and it was working, and I added a WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, StartDate) >= 1753 and it works, thanks.